# How to move partition in a usb to the first position

Tags: linux, partition, usb, usb-drive

I've Recalbox installed in the USB with 16 gb 3.0. It's partitionated in 4 because Recalbox needs at least 3 partitions, and it has a fourth partition of 5 gb that is called Documents. The problem comes when I try to access that partition on Windows. On Windows 10 Pro and Home it's not detected, only on Enterprise it is detected. It's a primary partition, but it's in the end of the drive, I read Windows only detects the first and primary partition in the drive, so I want to move Documents to there, but I don't know if it's possible or if it can damage Recalbox.

[image: USB partitions]

Comment: You can't. Even if it is possible theoritically, it's too hard for you to practice.

Comment: @神秘德里克: This is actually possible. Either by re-ordering the partition table (as describet in RudiC's answer) or by actually moving the filesystems on the drive. You would need to shrink the filesystems first and then have sufficient space on the drive. Only if there is not enough space, one would need to copy one of the larger filesystems onto another drive.

Comment: @Hermann Different software may have different opinion about the order of partition, the entry order in partition table or the actual address of partition.Only portable way is to keep these two synchronized. So as I said, OP needs to move partition data, which is too hard for him.

Comment: Another workaround would be assign a driver letter in Windows disk manager.

Answer (score 1):

I did that with `fdisk` / `parted` (needs some keystrokes, though) for eactly the same reason: Have MS-Win recognize the second partition on a stick:

```
Device     Boot    Start      End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1            361  4096360 4096000    2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdd2       12288361 15633407 3345047  1,6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdd3              1      360     360  180K  1 FAT12
/dev/sdd4        4096361 12288360 8192000  3,9G 83 Linux
```

Comment: To elaborate: The partition table does not need to list the partitions in the order they are on the drive. In this example, the first partition is not at the start of the drive. Please note that a start sector of 1 is rarely used for reasons of alignment.

Comment: The start sector 1 is used to simulate an old DOS boot floppy (see: 180kB) for an ooold tool...